# Get server folder path and Request.IsAjaxRequest() in HandleError attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, exception

I'm trying to extending HandleErrorAttribute in an ASP.Net MVC4 application. But the problem is i can not get the path of ~/App_Data. Another problem is i want to define whether it is an AjaxRequest. My code is as follows-

```
using sCommonLib;
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using sCommonLib;

public class HandleErrors:System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(System.Web.Mvc.ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {       
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            var path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"); //need help here              
            string actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
            Type controllerType = filterContext.Controller.GetType();
            var method = controllerType.GetMethod(actionName);
            var returnType = method.ReturnType;

            if (returnType.Equals(typeof(JsonResult)))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
                {
                    Data = "Some error."
                };
            }

            if (returnType.Equals(typeof(ActionResult))
            || (returnType).IsSubclassOf(typeof(ActionResult)))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                {
                    ViewName = "URL to the errror page"
                };
            }
        }

        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    var path = HSystem.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data"); // here              
    string actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    Type controllerType = filterContext.Controller.GetType();
    var method = controllerType.GetMethod(actionName);
    var returnType = method.ReturnType;

    if (returnType.Equals(typeof(JsonResult)))
    {
        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = "Some error."
        };
    }

    if (returnType.Equals(typeof(ActionResult)) || (returnType).IsSubclassOf(typeof(ActionResult)))
    {
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "URL to the errror page"
            };
    }
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: this is one part of the questions. What about the ajaxRequest?